# Garbage Collector Listeners

Tags: java, weak-references

I read an small article at some point about adding some callbacks to WeakReference objects that would be triggered upon garbage collection. Now, no mater how much I search, I cannot find it.

I need a way to execute some code whenever a weak referenced object is destroyed. I know that it can be done, I just don't remember how or whether I need a WeakReference or something else like a WeakHasMap?

Comment: I think you mean roughly http://java.dzone.com/articles/finalization-and-phantom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ReferenceQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue.html)s to archieve that. You might want to look into [`PhantomReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html)s, too, depending on what you're actually trying to do (but `WeakReference`s work with the queues, too). Just create a reference queue and pass it as a second argument to the reference-constructor. When the GC remove the object, the reference is enqueued and you can get it using `remove()` (blocking) or `poll()` (non-blocking) on your queue.

There is an alternative: implementing [`finalize`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29). It'S much less flexible though and runs in another thread, too (so you still have concurrency - with the addition of not even knowing which thread will execute it). The ReferenceQueue is superiour in all aspects.

Comment: Yes I did have a look at that, but I was hoping for something more automated without having a thread running and checking. Something more of a listener rather than a queue.

Comment: A thread which uses `remove` essentially IS a listener performance wise, since it does block until data is available. YOu cannot get tihs to work without a dedicated thread, as the GC doesn't stop/pause the main thread, so it continues to do whatever it'S doing  - how should it run any listener if it'S doing something else already?

Comment: (tl;dr: GC is running asynchronously in its own thread, therefore you need another thread to watch that queue. GC cannot execute anything on it's own reliably - which is why using `finalize()` isn't reliable. `finalize` however IS an alternative. Just don't trust it to always run.)

Comment: Well a listener could be a simple callback added to the ReferenceQueue that would be executed once something new is added. But your right, using 'remove' in a thread would be a possible solution. Thanks for your quick answers.